# How to stop the fade in / fade out on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, media-queries

I have created a simple fade in and fade out. I am also trying to stop the animation process on mobile device.I am able to access below code on computer but i want to  stop fadeIn and fadeOut on mobile device.
    Please help me

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
            <img class="bgfade" src="img/background1.png">
            <img class="bgfade" src="img/background2.jpg">
            <img class="bgfade" src="img/background3.jpg">
        </div>
```

**css**

```
#wrap{
    position:fixed;; 
    z-index:-1; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    background-color:black;
}

#wrap img.bgfade{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    background-position: center;

}

img {
    transition: all .10s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .10s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .10s linear;
    -o-transition: all .10s linear;
}

#wrap img {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(30%);
   filter: brightness(40%);
}
```

**js**

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('img.bgfade').hide();
var dg_H = $(window).height();
var dg_W = $(window).width();
$('#wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});

function anim() {
    $("#wrap img.bgfade").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(2000);
    $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(2000);
    setTimeout(anim, 3000);
}
anim();})
$(window).resize(function(){window.location.href=window.location.href})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's dirty solution but you'll get idea of what you need to do.
[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/adjbLv)

What I done is just placed some `!important` rules based on media query breakpoint. You try to animate your images with class, and clear out those ugly code I put there, NOTE: it's just to help you with logic.

Comment: Mr.Zlatko now fede in and fedeout stop but can you help me to display only one image on mobile device on background

Comment: I tried background image and its work for me thanks Mr.Zlatko

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `stop()` method is used to stop animations or effects before it is finished.

Comment: You are right but i have to stop on mobile device so where i can use stop()?

Comment: there are three images i have to display one image only on mobile device